# mcafee mysql audit plugin version vs mysql version

Tags: mysql, linux, plugins

Actually I was searching a opensource tool/plugin/command by which I can get some logs suppose who executed a truncate command at which time from which IP etc. but not getting such type a feature in open source (don't want to enable general log as wants specific/limited logs).

Fortunately I got information of mcafee mysql audit plugin and first I tested it on my testing environment where mysql version was 5.5.51, so after trying different versions of plugin I got "audit-plugin-mysql-5.5-1.1.0-633-linux-x86_64.zip" this plugin and successfully implemented it, also getting logs whatever I wants.

Now my problem is that we are using 5.6.34 in our production environment and there are so many version of plugin for 5.6 at "http://dl.bintray.com/mcafee/mysql-audit-plugin/#audit-plugin-mysql-5.5-1.0.5-464-linux-i386.zip" and I can't download them one by one and test in production environment.

Someone can help if have any logic/mapping that which mcafee mysql audit plugin work with which mysql version.

I will be very thankful.

Comment: OS is linux with 64 bit, I have also tried from here: "https://bintray.com/mcafee/mysql-audit-plugin/release" but it is also not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating this answer on my own post, so that if any other person is facing same issue then can get benefit.

When I posted this issue, there was latest plugin available at "http://dl.bintray.com/mcafee/mysql-audit-plugin/", it was "audit-plugin-mysql-5.6-1.1.0-633", which was not compatible with latest mysql 5.6 version like 5.6.31 or 5.6.34.

So after my request on github through request "https://github.com/mcafee/mysql-audit/issues/149" they have updated latest plugin for 5.6 as "audit-plugin-mysql-5.6-1.1.0-638", which is working fine.

Now you can use below plugin-

```
mysql5.5.51 : audit-plugin-mysql-5.5-1.1.0-633-linux-x86_64.zip
mysql5.6.31 : audit-plugin-mysql-5.6-1.1.0-638-linux-x86_64.zip
mysql5.6.34 : audit-plugin-mysql-5.6-1.1.0-638-linux-x86_64.zip
```